# VBA Code runs inconsistently

Tags: vba, excel

Hi there i have this code that allows cells in one sheet to be deleted , thereafter, the deletion would be updated in another sheet. This code has been running well until today when i tried again it kept giving me errors at 
   `Set delRange = Union(delRange, .Cells(j, i))`. The error message is "Method'Union' of object_'Global'failed"
I tried it on other workbooks and at first it worked, subsequently it gave the same error again . May i know why am i getting this error and are there any solutions to debug this ?Thank you

```
Sub Database()

Dim rng As Range, rngError As Range, delRange As Range
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
Dim wks As Worksheet

On Error Resume Next

Set rng = Application.InputBox("Select cells To be deleted", Type:=8)

On Error GoTo 0

If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub Else rng.Delete

For k = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count 'runs through all worksheets

  Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(k)

  With wks

    For i = 1 To 7 '<~~ Loop trough columns A to G

        '~~> Check if that column has any errors
        On Error Resume Next

        Set rngError = .Columns(i).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors)

        On Error GoTo 0

        If Not rngError Is Nothing Then
            For j = 1 To 100 '<~~ Loop Through rows 1 to 100
                If .Cells(j, i).Text = "#REF!" Then
                    '~~> Store The range to be deleted

             If delRange Is Nothing Then
              Set delRange = .Cells(j, i)

               Else
            Set delRange = Union(delRange, .Cells(j, i))


                    End If
                End If
             Next j
         End If

     Next i

  End With

Next k

'~~> Delete the range in one go
If Not delRange Is Nothing Then delRange.Delete
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Union` of ranges in different sheets is not allowed, so the code will fail if it finds `"#REF!"` in 2 different sheets.

Move:

```
If Not delRange Is Nothing Then delRange.Delete
Set delRange = Nothing
```

Before:

```
Next k
```

Comment: When i put the delRange=nothing, it gives me error message like "Object variable or with block variable not set:After removing that line, the code works but gives me an object required message. What should i do? @user3964075

Comment: @Niva sorry, fixed obvious mistake.